# How to Encrypt session id Using Hyperlink. Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net

How to Encrypt session id Using Hyperlink. Vb.Net

Heres my code but its not working...

au8550_h4.NavigateUrl = String.Format("~/operator/printAU8550.aspx?Au8550VesselID=", Server.UrlEncode(EncryptString(Session("vid").ToString)))

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't plain and simple...

Encrypting the session value has no effect. The session cookie is already an arbitrary value, encrypting it will just generate another arbitrary value that can be sniffed. The only real solution is HTTPS or even SSL.

Have you heard of session hijackers...